# Irritating message when editing several tag wikis

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, tag-wiki

When one edits several tag wikis - which is quite useful when detailing the differences between two tags - this message pops up when saving. (ELU.SE style)

[image: ELU_Tag_Wiki_Edit]

This message is shown when saving the second tag wiki. (Save first wiki, change tab, save second.)

If one tries saving it again 20 seconds later the same 30 second message pops up. Although after 30 seconds total one can save the second tag wiki entry.

It is a bit irritating since it's just sensitive to the context *save tag wiki* and not the context *save tag wiki X*. Furthermore the fixed time is not helping either.

Comment: Are you saying that *only* the message should be removed or the actual 30 second limit?

Comment: A better message would be a good step. I can see why SE doesn't accept several *posts* at the same time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The message is there for a reason. You can't post multiple tag wiki edits at the same time to prevent misusing the system. Rate limits are there to prevent the damage that one user can perform within a small time before it gets noticed.

I understand the error message and the rate limit are irritating, but I guess you have to live with it. And to be honest, how often do you come across this situation? I think this is an exceptional case which doesn't need fixing.